# Cocopods can not be installed Flutter and VSCode

Tags: flutter, macos

I tried to use flutter and everything okey but I have a problem with Cocopods.
the error I get is:

CocoaPods not installed.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

also i get: [AERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6. Try installing it with `gem install drb -v 2.0.6` and then running the current command again
drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

when I tried to type
sudo gem install cocopods
nothing change after asking for my password.

I am working in VSCode.
anyone can help?

I tired typing gem install drb -v 2.0.6 and the error:
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

and sudo gem install cocopods: nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command to install

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: zsh: command not found: brew

Comment: Follow steps here to install https://brew.sh/